# Rails Empty Controller Serves Correct View file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help understanding steps taken to create controllers and routes in a beginner Rails app.  I have been coding in Javascript for the past 6 months and I am now trying my hand at Ruby on Rails. I am going to keep my questions focused on how and why controllers and routes look and work the way they do in Rails.

So first,

```
Rails generate controller welcome index
```

I ran this in terminal and it behaved as expected:  *mydomain*/welcome/index served a welcome page.

My question is about the route and the controller that make this possible.

Within routes.rb, we have a solitary one line of code:

```
get 'welcome/index'
```

I'm assuming that this file is taking a client request for *mydomain*/welcome/index and then sends this request to the welcome_controller.rb in the app folder.  If that is indeed correct, why don't we see the logic  or the process of passing the request along to the controller in this file?

Second question: once we open welcome_controller.rb we see this

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

I don't see anything that designates the app to look into the index.html.erb file or the view file.  (But this file is indeed executed or compiled <--not sure about my terminology)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the framework's "magic". It's covered more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) in the docs; the convention of 'action name == layout filename' is one of the ways of speeding up development time by *abstracting* away the complex and boring stuff. If I had to handle all the code to render html for every new controller I'd be about five years behind.

The routes file - and in fact most of rails code you generate - can be thought of as more of a config file written in code, rather than a complete routing program that is self contained.

This controller class inherits from ApplicationController which in turn inherits from ActionController::Base - which handles much of the setup and rendering. It's probably much too complicated to read through yourself at this stage of learning ruby due to the complex inheritance and class structure, but the doc above helps explain what you need to know functionally.

However, if you want to handle the request yourself manually in Ruby, that is also a good bridge from learning js to learning ruby and rails, look into something like Sinatra which is much more direct and shall we say 'node-like' for a server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; Most of what you've learned and described in your question can be termed Rails architecture/framework (a design with different components and infrastructure such as Model, View, Controller, helper, etc), and the codes that you, as a ruby on rails (RoR) programmer will put, for instance in between

```
def index

end
```

are the instructions that will be executed where request comes through. Those are user-cases specific requests such as I want a list of an item, I want to delete an item, etc.  The codes would be written in ruby language.  I wish I put this as a comment (but comment has a different purpose) because am sure there are gurus here who will give better answer!
Examples you might be familiar with in Javascript is you have DOM, selector, events, actions, etc. such as:

```
$(function(){  // call jQuery

    // begin coding (making selection and do action)

    $("button").click(function(){  // on event of clicking a button      
    $("h3").css("color", "red");  //do action
    });

    }); //end of code

}); // end of jQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how Rails route works, please visit [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), after this, you can read [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) and get more details